# java android R cannot be resolved to a variable error

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

im working on an excercise for a class where we build a cannon app game for android, shown here in this link.

http://www.sci.tamucc.edu/~akatangur/su12/COSC4590/Androidfp_07.pdf

the entire walkthrough is here. so it should have no problem if i copy the instructions exactly. yet i cant compile because i get this same error  R cannot be resolved to a variable" "

when i try and clean the project i get this:

```
[2012-07-18 16:19:34 - CannonGame]   C:\Users\Gaming\workspace\CannonGame\res\menu\main.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').
[2012-07-18 16:30:45 - CannonGame] W/ResourceType( 5384): Bad XML block: header size 169 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
```

im a bit confused can someone explain this and how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? Assuming you are in Eclipse.

Comment: yes i cleaned the project and when i push clean it gives me that error above

Comment: When you look at the main.xml file do you see any red exclamation marks? Make sure you click on the source tap to see the actual XML text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define your string `menu_setting` in `values/strings.xml` like

```
<resources>
<string name="menu_setting">Your String</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: @anthony, I hope you didn't just copy paste--he missed an 's'. the name should be "menu_settings" like it says in the error.

Answer (score 0):

add title tag to your String.xml file

```
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
```